# Detect all-caps usage in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I write a JavaScript function that detects if the user is typing in all-caps in a `<textarea>`, and disallow submitting of the form until the offender has corrected their text? Understandably, a definition of all-caps is up for some debate, but here's what I'm aiming to achieve:

- *YOU CAN'T DO THAT. IT'S NOT SMART.* is obviously what I'm trying to snake out, because it's obnoxious.
- *I like this this school.* is acceptable because single letter "all capital" words are a part of the English language.
- *I mean, COME ON! This is ridiculous!* should this be acceptable? In a text field that doesn't support rich text, a user needs to be able to express emphasism. I think this should be acceptable.

Anyone have any suggestions? I imagine a regex is in order.

Comment: Probably you got to look for ASCII chars > 95.

Comment: Maybe just set a threshold for the percent of uppercase characters permitted?  No more than 50%?  I think the answer won't be hard once you specify the problem more precisely.

Comment: Your definition still isn't exact enough. How would you measure that? At most *n* words in caps allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure defining a threshold is appropriate, because the user could essentially type every second word in all caps and maintain the under 50% threshold, no? I think there needs to be some sort of logic applied

Comment: @JodyHeavener - the user can say filthy, terribly things in lowercase too.  :)  Point is, you need to define that logic, then you can easily write a regexp or whatever you want to apply it.

Comment: I think you need to match lowercase with a regex... and if that is found then fail the validation routine? right? something like `isValid = "abcdefGHIJKL".match(/[a-z]/g).length > 1`

Comment: If the text area contains NO lower-case letters, and it contains ANY upper-case letters, then it's all-caps. The second check avoids complaining if the field is just numbers (although that seems unlikely for a textarea.

Comment: you might also add a classname to the field like "notucase", then in your validation `valid = $(".notucase").filter(function(){return !!$(this).val().match(/[a-z]/g).length}).length` this way you can only hit fields that matter and skip numeric fields and other fields that don't matter.

Comment: hmm, there must be some condition which you must think of to separate the validation among the capital letters.

Answer (score 6):

Javascript function for checking that a string has uppercase letters but no lowercase letters:

```
function allCaps(word) {
    var containsUpper = /[A-Z]/.test(word);
    var containsLower = /[a-z]/.test(word);

    return containsUpper && !containsLower;
}
```

Comment: That's quite an ugly solution when just `word.toUpperCase() === word` is enough.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Not necessarily because the solution `word.toUpperCase() === word` will validate as true if word === 12345 or .... or some other string that contains no letters.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest getting a ratio of uppercased letters. Here is a way:

```
function getCapsRatio(val) {
    // Get the number of uppercase letters
    var up = (val.match(/[A-Z]/g) || '').length,

    // Get the number of letters (no space)
        fullLetters = (val.match(/[^\s+]/g) || '').length;

    // So the ratio of uppercase letters compared to downcase is...
    return (up * 100) / fullLetters;
}
```

So you'd use this function like this:

```
var ratio = getCapsRatio(value);
if (ratio > 50) {
    // 50% of uppercase letters? this guy is all caps!
}
```

This should be  studied, but I guess 50% is a good ratio to think the guy is all caps.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps simply this this :

```
 /[a-z]/i.test(str) && str.toUpperCase () == str
```

Compare the original string with itself up-cased, if equal then user has typed only upper-case letters.

Comment: This will validate incorrectly if someone types a string that contains no alphabet letters. Let's say someone asks: "How old are you?" and the person replies "13". The system won't let them send the reply "13" because it

Comment: will think it's all caps with the toUpperCase way

Comment: Good point @chrislondon . I have added a test to resolve that issue.